# how to insert data in multiple mongodb collections using mongoose & node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am new in node.js. I'm trying to store three different objects in collection in mongodb using node.js.

index.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var control = require('./controllers/controller');
var port = 3200;

mongoose.connect(
    'mongodb://localhost:27017/create-company',
    {useNewUrlParser: true},
    err => {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log('connection successfully');
    }
)
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use('/api', control);

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('start your server on: ', port);
});
```

model.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var CompanySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    companyname: String,
    founder: String,
    contact: String,
    location: String
});
var company = mongoose.model("company", CompanySchema); 

var BranchSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    branchname: String,
    branchmanger: String,
    contact: String,
    location: String  
});
var branch = mongoose.model('branch', BranchSchema);

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({[enter image description here][1]
    username: String,
    userrole: String,
    age: Number
});
var user = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);

module.exports = {
    company: company,
    branch: branch,
    user: user
}
```

controller.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var company = require('../models/model');

router.post('/create_company', function (req, res) {
    var new_company = new company.company(req.body);
    var new_branch = new company.branch(req.body);
    var new_user = new company.user(req.body);

   new_company.save(function (err, data) {
        if (err) 
        res.send(data);
        console.log(data);
    });

    new_branch.save(function (err, data) {
        if (err) 
        res.send(data);
        console.log(data);
    });


    new_user.save(function (err, data) {
        if (err)
        res.send(data);
        console.log(data);
    });

});
```

i am pass data to postman like this:

[{
    "companyname": "stack",
    "founder": "alex",
    "contact": "1234567890",
    "location": "in"
},
    {
        "branchname": "am",
        "branchmanager": "abc",
        "contact": "8754216523",
        "location": "inn"
    },
    {
        "username": "xyz",
        "userrole": "admin",
        "age": "23"
}]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UAkK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three problems here:

You are attempting to create a new document by passing the entire body to the constructor. You need to pass the correct array element to it's respective constructor.

```
var new_company = new company.company(req.body[0]);
var new_branch = new company.branch(req.body[1]);
var new_user = new company.user(req.body[2]);
```

You are attempting to send a response more than once. You need to coordinate the callbacks so that you send the response after they all have completed. I suggest you use promises to accomplish this, fortunately Mongoose supports promises.

```
Promise.all([
    new_company.save(),
    new_branch.save(),
    new_user.save()
]).then(function (data) {
    res.send(data);
    console.log(data);
});
```

You are not handling the error correctly. Your `if (err)` statement will cause `res.send(data)` to be called when there is an error, this is certainly not desired. Using the promise based method defined above error handling is very simple.

```
Promise.all([
    new_company.save(),
    new_branch.save(),
    new_user.save()
]).then(function (data) {
    res.send(data);
    console.log(data);
}).catch(function (err) {
    res.status(400).send('Uh oh! Something bad happened.');
    console.error(err);
});
```

If you use ES6 syntax you can write a synchronous looking route, which may be more familiar if you are coming from a different language:

```
router.post('/create_company', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const [company, branch, user] = req.body;
        const data = await Promise.all([
            new company.company(company).save(),
            new company.branch(branch).save(),
            new company.user(user).save()
        ]);
        res.send(data);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).send('Uh oh! Something bad happened.');
        console.error(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks jake. very very usefull content. thanks again give your time for my code.